# .net core 3.1 to .net Core 5 upgrade gives wrong conversion for datetime values? Any document for this breaking changes and solution

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Recently upgrade one application from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5. For some reason the DateTimeKind was Local in 3.1 and now it is UTC in .NET 5.

I created a simple project showing this problem,

https://github.com/ShehulCS/Dotnet5DateTimeIssue

Question,

1. Can anyone please confirm from Microsoft docs, if this was the change they introduce between 2 versions, is it a bug or new design?
   Online search doesn't lead me to anything useful on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're describing is related to a bug fix.

In short, the `Z` at the end of an ISO 8601 timestamp explicitly means UTC.  The bug was that when such a value is obtained through model binding, it was previously being interpreted as `DateTimeKind.Local` instead of `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  That bug has been corrected in 5.0.

- The bug is described in this issue:
  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11584
- It was fixed in this PR:
  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/24893
- A request to backport the fix to 3.1 was made (but denied) here:
  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27618

The *new* behavior is correct.  If you were relying on the old behavior, you probably have other .NET code that needs to be corrected.

Comment: Sorry I marked your answer correct, but I am not clear on why when we supply parameter value as date=2021-04-20T00:00:00-04:00 , it still shows up as UTC in .NET 5, shouldn't it be Local as no Z is present and EST Timezone offset is present?

Comment: I agree that should it still be `Local` if passed an offset like `-04:00`.  You might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues) and reference the other one.  In the meantime, I suggest that if you are passing values with offsets, that you use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.  The local time zone of your server shouldn't be part of the equation.

Comment: Keep in mind that even though such a value would have a `Local` kind, the actual date/time parts would be adjusted to whatever the local server time zone is set to.  That's another reason to use `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: In my fork here you can see the differences between the serialized date.

https://github.com/dragos-durlut/Dotnet5DateTimeIssue

One has offset and one doesn't